# different settings for ido-find-file and ido-switch-buffer

Tags: hooks, ido

I like arbitrary substring matching for buffer completion but I want to disable it when completing file names or directories.  The idea is to set `ido-enable-prefix` to `t` only when `ido-find-file` is being used, and `nil` otherwise.

So something like this looks like it should work but it doesn't.

```
(setq ido-enable-prefix nil)

(defun ido-init-file-dir ()
  (when (or (eq ido-cur-item 'file) (eq ido-cur-item 'dir))
    (set (make-local-variable 'ido-enable-prefix) t)))

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-init-file-dir)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was using `set` and `make-local-variable` instead of just `setq`.  Working version:

```
(defun ido-setup-file-dir ()
  (when (or (eq ido-cur-item 'file) (eq ido-cur-item 'dir))
    (setq ido-enable-prefix t)))

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-setup-file-dir)
```